# Let's play Name that Gadol - women wearing Tallis story

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, rabbis, tallit-gadol, agada-stories-legends

There is a story that I have heard with multiple names being used as the Rabbi in the story.  It goes like this:

A woman came to [insert name of Torah Sage here] and said that it would enhance her religious experience to wear a Tallis, and could she do so.  He advised her to take things step by step, and first try a Tallis without the strings in it and see how she felt.  She came back after a week and informed him of how inspired and uplifted she had felt through the experience, and she was ready for the next step.  (There are longer versions, but I'll cut to the chase.) [Insert name of Torah Sage here] told her that a four cornered garment without the strings is at best meaningless, so apparently she gets her religious inspiration from something other than Mitzvos, and a Tallis isn't necessary.

Can anyone identify, with credible, *documented* sources, who the Rabbi in the story was?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/12/women-wearing-tallit/ No one really knows if that story ever happened.

Comment: הוא הציע לה ללבוש בגד של ארבע כנפות בלי ציציות במשך שלושה חודשים ואז לחזור אליו. לאחר שלושה חודשים היא חזרה ואמרה שזו הייתה החוויה הכי מרגשת בחייה. אמר לה הגרי"ד: "במשך שלושה חודשים לבשת בגד ללא שום ערך דתי או הלכתי, א"כ זה מגלה שההרגשה שלך באה ממקור שהוא מחוץ למצווה", ולא נתן לה את הסכמתו ללבוש טלית).

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=519801601439424&id=369334133152839

Comment: @preferred I can't tell if that's from R' Aviner or his students who manage that facebook page.  If you could clarify that it's the former, it'd make a valid answer.

Comment: I heard a parallel story about tefillin without the parshiyos.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That furthers the impression that it's apocryphal

Comment: I heard it in the name of Rav Yosef B. Soloveitchik. No documentation though.

Comment: I heard this story about R. Yosef Dov Soloveichik z"l from a student of his.
(This would explain the degree of uncertainty about the identity of the rabbi as many people refrain from mentioning the Rav's name, or use various indirect ways to reference him)

Comment: does it matter who? regardless it's not a great story though. a naive but well meaning woman comes with a question to a Rabbi and he mocks with about a point not relevant to her question

Comment: @Dude I think the point of the story was to illustrate that she was not well-meaning...

Comment: @yEz according to what she was not well meaning? Her or the one who made a charade to deceive her rather than just explaining that women are not to wear a tallis?

Comment: @Dude the point wasn't that women are not to wear a tallis. The point is that women are not to find their fulfillment by trying to be like men.

Comment: @yEz No, the point is that anyone (men or women) shouldn't find Jewish meaning in halachically empty rituals.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess not knowing the actual character in the story, or if it ever really happened, we can't know for sure, but I don't think you are correct. The story was executed specifically in the context of someone asking to do something with the agenda to be something they aren't supposed to be. Is a tallis with tzitzis on all four corners a halachically empty ritual? If not, what was he trying to show this woman by having her perform empty rituals when she wanted to perform a non-empty one?

Comment: @yEz You still can't say "The point is that women are not to find their fulfillment by trying to be like men." What if the women had been unsatisfied by the fringeless-tallis bc she wasn't getting to have as many mitzva credits as men do? The point is to distinguish motivations based in commitment to and desire to fulfill Halacha vs external motivations unrelated (or incidentally related) to Judaism which can be quenched with halchically empty rituals. He wanted to test to see if her motivations were noble (in the above dichotomy) or, if they weren't, to use the moment for education.

Comment: @DoubleAA I disagree.